# Is the exponential map to the indefinite special orthogonal groups $SO^+(p,q)$ surjective?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, special-relativity

Is the exponential map to the identity component of the special indefinite orthogonal groups
$$ \mathrm{exp} \colon \mathfrak{so}(p,q) \to SO^+(p,q)$$
surjective?

Comment: No; I think this should already be false for $SO(2, 1)$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: I think it's actually true for $SO^+(2,1)=PSL(2)$, even though it is not true for $SL(2)$ (which is its 2-fold cover)

Comment: Hmm. Maybe? I hadn't thought about it beyond the double cover. In any case, the argument that works for the definite orthogonal groups (the spectral theorem) fails here.

Answer (score 10):

1. For the special orthogonal group $SO(d)$ and the restricted Lorentz group $SO^+(d,1)\cong SO^+(1,d)$, the [exponential maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map_%28Lie_theory%29)
   $$\begin{align}\exp: so(d)~~\longrightarrow~~& SO(d), \cr
   \exp: so(d,1)~~\longrightarrow~~& SO^+(d,1),\end{align}\tag{1} $$ are surjective. See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/160939/2451) related Phys.SE post and links therein.
2. *Simplest counterexample.* The exponential map
   $$\exp: sl(2,\mathbb{R})\oplus sl(2,\mathbb{R})~~\longrightarrow~~ SL(2,\mathbb{R})\times SL(2,\mathbb{R})\tag{2} $$
   for the split group
   $$SO^+(2,2)~\cong~[SL(2,\mathbb{R})\times SL(2,\mathbb{R})]/\mathbb{Z}_2 \tag{3}$$
   is *not* surjective. Here the $\mathbb{Z}_2$-action identifies
   $$\begin{align} (g_L,g_R)~~\sim~~&(-g_L,-g_R), \cr 
   g_L,g_R~\in~& SL(2,\mathbb{R})~:=~\{g\in {\rm Mat}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R}) \mid \det g~=~1\}.\end{align}\tag{4}$$
   One may show that a pair $$(g_L,g_R)~\in~SL(2,\mathbb{R})\times SL(2,\mathbb{R})\tag{5}$$ with $${\rm tr}(g_L)<-2\quad\text{and}\quad{\rm tr}(g_R)>2\tag{6}$$  (or vice-versa $L\leftrightarrow R$) is *not* in the image of the exponential map, even after $\Bbb{Z}_2$-modding.
3. More generally, one may prove for the indefinite orthogonal groups $SO^+(p,q)$, where $p,q\geq 2$, that the exponential map
   $$\exp: so(p,q)~~\longrightarrow~~ SO^+(p,q)\tag{7} $$ is *not* surjective, cf. e.g. Ref. 1.

References:

1. D.Z. Dokovic & K.H. Hofmann, Journal of Lie Theory 7 (1997) 171. The pdf file is available [here](http://www.heldermann-verlag.de/jlt/jlt07/DOKHOFPL.PDF).

Comment: Is the exponential map also injective on $SO(p)$?

Comment: No, already the case $d=2$ is not injective.